# return list<string> from WCF service called by jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, wcf, json

I have the following call to my service that is returning a `list<string>`

When I run this I get the error has occured message.

```
$(document).ready(function () //executes this code when page loading is done
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Services/pilltrakr.svc/getAllUsers",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        },
        error: function (message) {
            alert("error has occured : " + message);
        }
    });
});
```

**How do I return a list from my WCF Service?**

**Interface:**

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
                BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
                ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
List<string> getAllUsers();
```

**Class:**

```
public List<string> getAllUsers()
{
    userAccount ua = new userAccount();
    List<string> myUserList = new List<string>();
    myUserList = ua.getAllUsers();

    return myUserList;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I changed the BodyStyle attribute to WrappedRequest and then everything worked (I tried with both GET and POST).  The data was then returned.  Now my question is why did that change resolve this issue?  Do I always need to include a BodyStyle?

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
                    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
                    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    List<string> getAllUsers();
```

Comment: Can you include the error message?

Comment: I wonder why are you using POST for retrieving data?

Comment: @ladislav - Does it make a difference?

Comment: @Andre -I get a message box that states: An error has occured - [object XMLHttpRequest].  Then in Firebug it just states 500 Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the BodyStyle attribute to WrappedRequest and then everything worked (I tried with both GET and POST). The data was then returned. Now my question is why did that change resolve this issue? Do I always need to include a BodyStyle?